# How to convert CharArrayType from Visual Basic to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, char

I am updating an old program made in Visual Basic to C#. I can't seem to find an equivalent to the visual Basic class 'CharArrayType' in C#. Does anyone know if this class even has an equivalent in C#?

```
return (char[])CharArrayType
       .FromObject(LateBinding
                   .LateIndexGet(array, new object[] { 0 }, null));
```

Comment: This is a C# code, what's the `array` type and what's the VB code?

Comment: @Saeed Amiri This is the code I was given. It is C#, but it uses the VisualBasic.CompilerServices to make `CharArrayType` and other outdated classes work. I have to rewrite the code without the Compiler reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use an array of `char` like this:

```
char[] charArray = new char[] {'a','b','c'};
```

however there isn't an exact equivalent for this in dot.net.

For implementing functionality like [`FromString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.chararraytype.fromstring.aspx) you can do something like this:

```
var charArray = str.ToArray();
```

Other functionality is based on object. Note as well that `char[]` includes this feature as well.

Comment: If all your program requires is an array of `char` datatype and doesn't use the methods in `CharArrayType` class, then this is your solution!

Comment: @JohnB I'm not familiar with this class but as I can see in MSDN there isn't any magic with this, so it can be simulated to this version with some additional functionality, and I'm sure all of them can be done in .net, Also I'm sure can't use it in .Net except simulate it, so at the end you will reach to answer like what I said.

Comment: @JohnB I'm using many methods for this class, including `FromObject`, `ToString`, and `FromString`.

Comment: @user1015106 add your VB code and it's good to say what's the result of fromobject to simulate it, but you can't do it in .net, There is a crazy way, create a Com object of this class and use it in .net see http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx to see how to create com, but I personally prefer to use simulated one.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.chararraytype%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (going back as far as .NET 2.0):

> This class has been deprecated as of Visual Basic 2005. It is used
>   only to support the Visual Basic 2003 compiler and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.

So I suspect there is no current equivalent. For what are you using this class? As @Yuck asked, please show us the code.

Comment: ` return (char[])CharArrayType.FromObject(LateBinding.LateIndexGet(array, new object[]
                {
                    0
                }, null));`

Answer (score 0):

`CharArrayType` was deprecated in Visual Basic 2005.

This is more an an issue of a deprecated feature in the API than VB versus C# syntax.

Here are the methods it supports:

- [CharArrayType Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.chararraytype.aspx)

For more help, please answer these questions:

1. What version of Visual Studio and .NET Framework version are you using to create your updated program?
2. What methods in the `CharArrayType` class were you using in your old Visual Basic program?

Also, posting some code may help.

Comment: I didn't create this program, just updating it. I think it started as Visual Basic, then was changed to C# using Visual Basic Compiler Services. I'm not sure about the .Net Framework.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, but I'm not a programmer. I'm a self-taught intern. Forgive me for my lack of pragramming ability, but my only teacher is Google and two months of practice.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and .Net Framework 4.